# Parameterless constructor issue within webapi application using owin and ninject

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

I have a web api application in which I'd like to use **Owin**, **Oauth** and **Ninject** , So I have this configuration

**Dependency injector**

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private static IKernel kernel; 

    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
       // AddBindings();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    private static void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<INotifier>().To<Notifier>();
        kernel.Bind<IEventRepository>().To<EventRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ICrud<Config>>().To<CrudConfig>();
        kernel.Bind<ICrud<Evenement>>().To<CrudEvent>();
        kernel.Bind<IAccount>().To<Account>();
    }



    public static Lazy<IKernel> CreateKernel = new Lazy<IKernel>(() =>
    {
        //var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        AddBindings();

        return kernel;
    });


}
```

**StartUp class**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        //app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => NinjectDependencyResolver.CreateKernel.Value);
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

**Global.cs**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

I have this class also

```
 public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
        }        
    }
```

and I have this api controller :

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    #region ctors

    public AccountController()
    {

    }
    [Inject]
    public AccountController(INotifier _notifierParam,  IAccount _IAccount)
    {
        Notifier = _notifierParam; 
        Account = _IAccount;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

which derived from **BaseController** which is a class with no contructor.

the problem is when I make a call to service of the account controller I get this exception :

> "Message":"An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage":"An error
>   occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.",
>   "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException", "StackTrace":"   à
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)\r\n   à
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   à
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
>   "InnerException":{
>       "Message":"An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage":"Error activating INotifier\r\nNo matching bindings are available, and the type is not
>   self-bindable.\r\nActivation path:\r\n  4) Injection of dependency
>   INotifier into parameter _notifierParam of constructor of type
>   AccountController\r\n  3) Injection of dependency AccountController
>   into parameter resolutionRoot of constructor of type NamedScope\r\n 
>   2) Injection of dependency NamedScope into parameter resolutionRoot of
>   constructor of type OwinNinjectDependencyResolver\r\n  1) Request for
>   IDependencyResolver\r\n\r\nSuggestions:\r\n  1) Ensure that you have
>   defined a binding for INotifier.\r\n  2) If the binding was defined in
>   a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.\r\n 
>   3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.\r\n 
>   4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter
>   name matches the constructors parameter name.\r\n  5) If you are using
>   automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are
>   correct.\r\n",
>       "ExceptionType":"Ninject.ActivationException",
>       "StackTrace":"   à Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request)\r\n   à Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type
>   service, IContext parent)\r\n   à
>   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)\r\n
>   à Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext
>   context, ITarget target)\r\n   à
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2(ITarget
>   target)\r\n   à
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   à
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   à
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   à
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext
>   context)\r\n   à Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object
>   scope)\r\n   à Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()\r\n   à
>   Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding
>   binding)\r\n   à
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n 
>   à System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)\r\n   à
>   Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)\r\n   à
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   à
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)"} }

So I need to know :

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Check `Notifier` class. the error message states `Error activating INotifier`

Comment: Also how do you setup your dependency resolver.

Comment: Have you gone through all the suggestions in the exception message. I believe it is clearly telling you what you need to check to solve your problem. Noticed another example `Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.` I'm seeing two instances where you create a new `kernel`

Comment: @Nkosi please see my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing Dependency Injection approaches. Your are using OWIN for setting the ninject middleware for Web API but then you are managing Web API outside of OWIN (using the IIS pipeline):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //..
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    //..
}
```

The second mistake is that you are creating multiple Kernels, and your exception message is warning you to avoid this:

```
Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel
```

Start by refactoring your code. Manage Web API using only OWIN:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => NinjectDependencyResolver.CreateKernel.Value);
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
}
```

and remove this line from `Global.asax.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Then **ensure you are creating only one Kernel** for the entire application lifetime. You should have only one static instance of the Kernel, and reference it from any other object that needs it.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I apply the changes that you mention , i get this exception `The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler' is not null.
Nom du paramètre : handlers` !!!

Comment: Edited my answer. Try again using the new `Startup.cs` code.

Comment: thanks for the edit, after this modification the applications worked well but web api documentation area can't discover the controllers and its action !!

Comment: I cannot see any reference about Web Api documentarion your question. I suggest you to create a new question specifically for that purpose.